# need to use group by or i get a error, but i get wrong results

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, case

I have to see how many days all person have 'opdarcht's. So a sum of all the days between every 'opdracht'.startdate and enddate.

example opdracht:
stamboeknr     Startdate     Enddate
1              15/02/2014    18/02/2014
1              05/02/2014    25/02/2014
2              05/03/2014    15/03/2014

example Person:
stamboeknr     Name    Firstname
1              Peter   Griffen
2              Jo      Swanson

What i want:
stamboeknr    name           nrOfDays
1             Griffen Peter  23
2             Swanson Jo     10

(i use more data in my db)

The problem is that i also have to put everything in GROUP BY or i get a error. WHen i add everything in group  by (as used now) i see a person multiple times, but i want to see every person one time.

error message:
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 9 (--> on the line Case When Datediff...)
Column 'Opdracht.StartDatum' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

```
declare @Date int
set @Date = 15/02/2020

SELECT p.Stamboeknr, p.Name+ ' ' + p.Fistname AS Name, nrOfDays =
CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day,o.StartDate,@Date )> 0 THEN SUM(DATEDIFF(day, o.StartDate, @Date )) 
ELSE SUM(DATEDIFF(day, o.StartDate, o.EndDate)) END
FROM Person AS p INNER JOIN Opdracht AS o ON o.Stamboeknr = p.StamboekNr 
GROUP BY p.Stamboeknr, p.Naam, p.Voornaam, o.StartDate, o.EndDate
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm see you DECLARE @Date as int ??

I think you need DELCARE @Date as Date ,

and if you want set  @Date = '15/02/2020' , you need check is right Date Format

Comment: i changed it, but i still have the orriginal error that i have to add o.StartDate and o.EndDate in Group by while i only want to group by person...